# socket.io creates new connection on a new tab

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have used socket.io in my node.js application. When I have one my app in a browser, then new socket connection established, but when I open another tab in same browser, it also create new socket connection. why? and How Do I get socket id on my client?

Comment: Because it's establishing a new connection for each tab, which essentially is a new client. You could possibly incorporate [rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms).

Comment: @BenFortune, means each tab is new client for socket. right? If my user open 2-3 tab in a browser, then I have to emit messages on all that sockets from server? my session is single for all tabs, so why I am duplicating socket for each tab in a browser? thanks for a reply, and one more thing, I have new in this technology, that's why I am understanding this? thanks

Comment: Sessions are browser-wide, sockets are tab-wide, since you're creating a new http request for each tab, which invokes a new websocket request. The socket ID will be different for each client so you need a way of grouping them, which is where rooms come in. Add an example of your code and SO might be able to help.